# Can I use alias with NodeJS require function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, commonjs

I have an ES6 module that exports two constants:

```
export const foo = "foo";
export const bar = "bar";
```

I can do the following in another module:

```
import { foo as f, bar as b } from 'module';
console.log(`${f} ${b}`); // foo bar
```

When I use NodeJS modules, I would have written it like this:

```
module.exports.foo = "foo";
module.exports.bar = "bar";
```

Now when I use it in another module can I somehow rename the imported variables as with ES6 modules?

```
const { foo as f, bar as b } = require('module'); // invalid syntax
console.log(`${f} ${b}`); // foo bar
```

How can I rename the imported constants in NodeJS modules?

Comment: `foo` isn't exported directly, it's a property of `exports` (which I'm presuming `module` gets exported?), so you can't alias it, not in the `import`/`require` anyway

Answer (score 274, accepted):

Sure, just use the object destructuring syntax:

```
 const { old_name: new_name, foo: f, bar: b } = require('module');
```

Comment: For clarification: `const { prevName: newName } = require('../package.json');` I flipped it around and couldn't figure out why it didn't work for a couple minutes.

Comment: @technogeek1995 you are the real MVP.
logged in to SO to thank you!

Comment: If you're requiring a default export (something like `export default foo;`), "default" _is_ the name so you'd do: `const { default: newName } = require('module');`

Comment: In case, its module.exports = () => {some function} then you can assign any variable name you want. const anything = require('module');

Answer (score 17):

It is possible (tested with Node 8.9.4):

```
const {foo: f, bar: b} = require('module');
console.log(`${f} ${b}`); // foo bar
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a simple destructure would adhere to your request.

### Instead of:

```
var events = require('events');
var emitter = new events.EventEmitter();
```

### You can write:

```
const emitter = {EventEmitter} = require('events');
```

`emitter()` will alias the method `EventEmitter()`

Just remember to instantiate your named function: `var e =  new emitter();`

Comment: There is a little confusion. `emitter` variable is not alias of `EventEmitter`. It presents entire module. Testable code is `const events = {EventEmitter} = require('events'); assert(events.EventEmitter === EventEmitter);`

Answer (score -5):

I would say it is not possible, but an alternative would be:

```
const m = require('module');
const f = m.foo;
const b = m.bar;
```