# Google API renaming imported variable yields error

Tags: node.js, jwt, google-auth-library

I am working on authorizing a JWT token using the googleapis node package. I am following the example from this link: [Here](https://flaviocopes.com/google-api-authentication/) If I change the variable name of the imported package it will yield an error.

### Why does example 1 work but example 2 yields below error:

```
const jwt = new googleapi.auth.JWT(
                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth' of undefined
```

Example 1

```
'use strict'

const { google } = require('googleapis')

const scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(
  process.env.CLIENT_EMAIL,
  null,
  process.env.PRIVATE_KEY,
  scopes
)
const view_id = 'XXXXXXX'

jwt.authorize((err, response) => {
  google.analytics('v3').data.ga.get(
    {
      auth: jwt,
      ids: 'ga:' + view_id,
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'today',
      metrics: 'ga:pageviews'
    },
    (err, result) => {
      console.log(err, result)
    }
  )
})
```

Example 2

```
'use strict'

const { googleapi } = require('googleapis')

const scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
const jwt = new googleapi.auth.JWT(
  process.env.CLIENT_EMAIL,
  null,
  process.env.PRIVATE_KEY,
  scopes
)
const view_id = 'XXXXXXX'

jwt.authorize((err, response) => {
  googleapi.analytics('v3').data.ga.get(
    {
      auth: jwt,
      ids: 'ga:' + view_id,
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'today',
      metrics: 'ga:pageviews'
    },
    (err, result) => {
      console.log(err, result)
    }
  )
})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48952736/can-i-use-alias-with-nodejs-require-function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax

```
const { google } = require('googleapis')
```

is called Object destructuring.

What it actualy does is that it loads the required module and gets `google` property from that module and assing it to a variable also called `google`.

It is the same as this:

```
const google = require('googleapis').google;
```

So when you do this:

```
const { googleapi } = require('googleapis')
```

it is the same as this:

```
var googleapi = require('googleapis').googleapi;
```

The thing is that the `googleapis` module does not export a property called `googleapi`.

If you really want the name to be `googleapi` you can do this:

```
const { googleapi: google } = require('googleapis');
```

or

```
const googleapi = require('googleapis').google;
```

or even this:

```
const GoogleAPIs = require('googleapis');
const googleapi = GoogleAPIs.google;
```

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation!

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept it as a correct answer ;)