# re-require node file after writing to it with fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Inside a node server, I am fetching data (as a string) that gets written to  local file, after which I want to use the updated data inside my main function. After looking through solutions that delete the require.cache for that file and re-requiring it, the previous information in the file is still being cached -- meaning that if it was overwritten with new data, it still references the old, and if the file was blank before being overwritten, it will return undefined.

How can I force a re-evaluation of the data at runtime within my main function?

What I'm currently doing is require at the top:

```
let d_file = require("path_to_d_file.js")
```

then function for fetching data and writing it to the file:

```
const async_write = async () => {
    const new_data = await axios.get(url, headers);
    fs.writeFile("path_to_d_file.js", new_data.data, (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
    }
}
```

Execute this function and attempt to re-require data after clearing the cache:

```
const main_func = async () => {
    await async_write();
    delete require.cache[require.resolve("path_to_d_file")];
    d_file = require("path_to_d_file");

    d_file.stuff.map(() => <do things>)
}
```

But d_file.stuff is `undefined` if the file was previously empty, or the older data if the file was not previously empty. I even tried deleting the cache inside the callback of fs.writeFile and re-assigning the import variable there without success. I also attempted a lazy require instead of declaring it at the top and re-assigning as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37083469/11925070 with similar results.

Is there a way to do what I'm attempting to do here without reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

`fs.writeFile` is an asynchronous function and will take some milliseconds to finish the file writing. Since your code is not waiting for the callback of this function to return, the `require` is being called before the file write operation finishes.

You can either use [`fs.writeFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) or wait for the callback:

```
// ...
const new_data = await axios.get(url, headers);
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.writeFile("./path_to_d_file.js", new_data.data, (err) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        resolve();
    });
});
// ...
```

And you also can use [Dynamic `import()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/esm.html#esm_import_expressions) instead of `require`:

```
d_file = (await import("./path_to_d_file.js")).default;
```